# Login screen to show incorrect credentials

Tags: c#

I am making a login screen in c#. How would I make it so it shows specifically if the username or password is incorrect.

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        string username = "Tim";
        string password = "Hennings";
        if ((this.txtUsername.Text == username) && (this.txtPassword.Text == password)) 
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text == username && txtPassword.Text == password)
                MessageBox.Show("Log in successful");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username/Password please try again");
            txtUsername.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with that?

Comment: Yeah. Not seeing the question here. Actually there is no question. Maybe some english refresher: A question is a sentence ending in "?".

Comment: This should work? But I would recommend a database for storing the data.

Comment: Why don't you use the system password dialog?

Comment: Why are you checking the username and password twice?

Comment: You should NOT be telling the people logging on if it was the Username or the Password that they got wrong - just tell them they could not login with those credentials.

Why? - Someone trying to hack into there is going to be quite happy when he only has to try to guess at a Username first and then just a password.

Comment: @AndrewMack that's good advice if the 'forgotten password' facility doesn't leak which usernames are valid and invalid and I've yet to find a web site in the wild that doesn't.

Comment: Ah, true - that would be pretty bad. I'd like to see websites use email addresses instead of usernames then (there's plenty that do... I think... it's definitely not an original idea...). But I'm sure there's flaws with that as well, eh

Answer (score 2):

> How would I make it so it shows specifically if the username or password is incorrect [?]

You shouldn't. It is a security concern, when you give an attacker the details of exactly what went wrong.

For more details see:

[“Username and/or Password Invalid” - Why do websites show this kind of message instead of informing the user which one was wrong?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17816/2553)

Answer (score 0):

```
        string username = "Tim";
        string password = "Hennings";
        if(this.txtUsername.Text != username)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username please try again");
            txtUsername.Focus();
        }else if(this.txtPassword.Text != password)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong Password please try again");
            txtPassword.Focus();
        }else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Log in successful");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         {
            string username = "Tim";
            string password = "Hennings";
            string outputMessage = string.Empty;

            if (this.txtUsername.Text != username)
            {
                outputMessage = "Username incorrect";
            }

            if (this.txtPassword.Text != password)
            {
                outputMessage = "Password incorrect";
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputMessage)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(outputMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                // Password and Username matched so log them in.
            }

        }
    }
```